# How to display single object in template

Tags: angularjs

I know how to render a list of objects in a template using NgFor, but I can't find any info on displaying a single object that isn't in an array.

I have an API end point that returns the user profile, through my ProfileService:

```
find() {
  return this.http.get('/api/user/22/profile.json');
}
```

My component is setup like this:

```
export class ProfileListComponent implements OnInit {
  profile: any;

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { }

  loadProfile() {
    this.profileService.find()
      .subscribe(response => this.profile = response.json());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProfile();
  }

}
```

In my template, I don't want to use NgFor, I just want to display the profile's attributes like:

```
{{ profile.name }}
```

How do I accomplish this? Right now, I get an undefined error, as if profile doesn't exist.

Comment: What have you tried? Specifically, it seems that you know exactly how to accomplish your task, so what is wrong?

Comment: @tcooc I'm still learning so I can't tell you much more than I get an error in the console saying: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `profile` field stays undefined until the http response comes back and the callback initializing it is invoked. That's why you get that error. Use `ngIf` to avoid diplaying the profile while it's not there yet, or use

```
{{ profile?.name }}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!